# Why this thread doesn't work?

Tags: android, multithreading

i have an android app, with a actitity, that shows a map, with a position. This possition is updated on sharedPreferences with a service... ok, that works fine.

I need that my activity implements runnable to be a thread that read's the position of sharedPreferences each 1000ms and then update the item position on the map... but it doesn't works.

As i saw in debug mode, my thread doesn't work fine, ONLY ENTER ONE TIME on RUN() method... i mean that never enters into RUN() method again, only one time, cause this, the positions doesn't be updated on the map

What is wrong? why this thread doesn't work fine?

public class Locate extends MapActivity{

```
private TextView userText = null;
private TextView permissionText = null;
private TextView lastUpdateText = null;
private Button locateButton = null;
private Button traceButton = null;
private MapView mapView = null;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = null;
double lat;
double lng;
GeoPoint p;
MapController mc;

Drawable drawable;
Drawable drawable2;
MyItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay;
MyItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay2;

//para almacenar la config local de mi app, mostrarme o no en el mapa...
static SharedPreferences settings;
static SharedPreferences.Editor configEditor;

private MyLooper mLooper;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locate);

    userText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.User);
    permissionText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Permission);
    lastUpdateText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LastUpdate);
    locateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locate);
    traceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trace);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    mc = mapView.getController();

    settings=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    configEditor = settings.edit();

    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.minifriend); // Icono de la cara, para posiciones de mis amigos
    drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.miniicon2); // Icono del programa, para mi posicion GPS
    itemizedoverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, this); // Aqui almaceno otras posiciones gps
    itemizedoverlay2 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable2, this); // Aqui almaceno mi posicion gps

    if (this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) /// si he recibido datos del friend en el Bundle
    {
        updateFriendPosition();
    }

    if (settings.getBoolean("showMeCheckBox", true))
    {
        updateMyPosition();
    }


    locateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            //itemizedoverlay2.getItem(0).
            itemizedoverlay.clear();
            updateFriendPosition();
            itemizedoverlay2.clear();
            updateMyPosition();
        }
    });

    traceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks             
        }
    }); 

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// CODIGO PARA QUITAR EL FOCO DEL PRIMER TEXTEDIT Y QUE NO SALGA EL TECLADO DE ANDROID ///
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    //thread.start();
    mLooper = new MyLooper();
    mLooper.start();


}
private void updateFriendPosition() 
{
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();//get the intent & bundle passed by X
    userText.setText(bundle.getString("user"));
    permissionText.setText(bundle.getString("permission"));
    lastUpdateText.setText(bundle.getString("lastupdate"));
    String coordinates[] = {bundle.getString("lat"), bundle.getString("lon")};  
    lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(p, bundle.getString("user"), "Hi Friend!");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);// dibujo la estrella con la posicion actual del friend

    mc.animateTo(p); ///nos centra el mapa en la posicion donde esta nuestro amigo
    mc.setZoom(10);  /// ajusta el zoom a 10        
}
public void updateMyPosition()
{
    String coordinates[] = {settings.getString("mylatitude", null),settings.getString("mylongitude", null)};    
    lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(p, "Me", "My Position");
    itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);//dibujo mi icono para mostrarme a mi
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

/////metodos del hilo
/*
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Boolean fallo=false;
        itemizedoverlay2.clear();
        updateMyPosition();
        try{ Thread.sleep(1000);} 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            fallo=true;         
        }
    }
};

public void run() 
{   
    Looper.prepare();
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    Looper.loop();
}
*/




private class MyLooper extends Thread {
    public void run() {   
        while (mLooper==Thread.currentThread()) {
            // Your code here
            Boolean fallo=false;
            itemizedoverlay2.clear();
            updateMyPosition();
            try{ Thread.sleep(5000);} 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                fallo=true;         
            }
        }
    }


}
```

}

EXCEPTION WHEN I TRY TO SOLVE MY PROBLEM THE METHOD'S OF TOMS AND MARVINLABS ANSWERS:

```
    11-18 17:37:43.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:66)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:41)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:471)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5838)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5944)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5841)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5841)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1217)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1030)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1482)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
11-18 17:37:43.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you touching UI objects (a map overlay) from a background thread? Don't do that, you're bound to get into trouble. If you really must have a background thread, use an AsyncTask and only touch UI objects from onPostExecute().

However, from a quick read of your code I suspect you don't need a thread at all. What's wrong with a simple `Handler` on the UI thread which you simply `postDelayed(5000)` to?

EDITED TO ADD:

Replace this line

```
private MyLooper mLooper;
```

With this:

```
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        itemizedoverlay2.clear();
        updateMyPosition();
        queueRunnable();
    }
};
private void queueRunnable() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 5000);
}
```

Then remove these lines:

```
mLooper = new MyLooper();
mLooper.start();
```

and replace them with:

```
mHandler = new Handler();
queueRunnable();
```

Finally remove the MyLooper class you don't need.

Comment: can you give me a code example of how to do it without a thread? i still will can press butons and do interaction with this ui?

Comment: and also i am retrieving info to update my map from SharedPreferences, but i am updathing the map on this ui, not on other ui

Comment: and also this ui haves another buttons and other functionality

Comment: Yes. I got to nip out for 10 minutes but when I come back I'll update my answer with code.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!! doesn't give me crash!!!!!! THANKS MATE!!!!!! WOOOW, but now i have another problem, the new position of the items only get repainted on the map when i move or zoom the map :S how i can solve it?

Comment: Weird, I thought Mapview drew itself continually more or less. Try calling mapView.invalidate() at the end of updateMyPosition().

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having your activity implement Runnable, you should make a private class to your activity:

```
public class Locate extends MapActivity {   
    // ...
    private MyLooper mLooper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        mLooper = new MyLooper(this);
        mLooper.start();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to stop the thread here and release the reference 
        // held by the activity (else you will leak memory)
        mLooper = null;
    }

    private class MyLooper extends Thread {
        public void run() {   
            while (mLooper==Thread.currentThread()) {
                // Your code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i get an error here: mLooper = new MyLooper(this);   ERRROR:  The constructor Locate.MyLooper(Locate) is undefined

Comment: and also, if  locate implementews Runnable, i have to implement run... are you sure that your code is ok ?

Comment: i repair your code, remove the implements runnable of the first line and remove this from the new Mylooper line... and doesn't works... the same ocurrs, the thread only do Run method ONE TIME

Comment: Sorry, your activity does not implement Runnable anymore (code corrected). And you need to define a constructor for MyLooper as well if you want to pass it a Context or an Activity (code corrected).

Comment: wich kind of handler i need? Android.os ? or java.util ?

Comment: Do you have a handler in your MyLooper class?

Comment: OK i tryed with android.os and your new code and still didn't work.... i add the handler too, didn't work, same problem

Comment: I don't use Looper usually, just plain Threads (code updated)

Comment: i have to pass the context to the MyLooper or not mate?

Comment: Hi mate, this way gives me a exception and crashes my app, you have the logcat on first question, read it plz

Answer (score 0):

I'd use MarvinLabs approach, but implement the while cycle in a different way:

```
public class Locate extends MapActivity {   
    // ...
    private MyLooper mLooper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        mLooper = new MyLooper();
        mLooper.start();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to stop the thread here and release the reference 
        // held by the activity (else you will leak memory)
        mLooper = null;
    }

    private class MyLooper extends Thread {
        public void run() {   
            while (true) {
                // Your code here

                //After executing your code, sleep for 1000ms
                try {
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                       //Treat the exception
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also, instead of while(true) you can have a variable that would serve has a flag to inform the while cycle when to stop. That would make things easier when it's time to stop the thread.

That would be something along these lines:
**Modified to use Handler**

```
public class Locate extends MapActivity {   
    // ...
    private MyLooper mLooper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        mLooper = new MyLooper(new Handler());
        mLooper.start();

        //When it's time to stop
        mLooper.setKeepRunningFalse();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to stop the thread here and release the reference 
        // held by the activity (else you will leak memory)
        mLooper = null;
    }

    private class MyLooper extends Thread {
        //Your flag
        private boolean keepRunning;
        private Handler locateHandler;

        public MyLooper(Handler locateHandler)
        {
              this.locateHandler = locateHandler;
        }

        public void run() {   
            while (keepRunning) {
                //When you want to execute some code that accesses Locate objects do this
                locateHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                //Your code here
                                //This code will be executed by the thread that owns the objects, thus not throwing an exception.

                        }
                });


                //After executing your code, sleep for 1000ms
                try {
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                       //Treat the exception
                }
            }
        }

            //Method to change the flag to false
            public void setKeepRunningFalse()
            {
               this.keepRunning = false;
            }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi mate, this way, like MarvinLabs way, gives me a exception and crashes my app, you have the logcat on first question, read it plz

Comment: Have you tried putting the entire onCreate and run methods inside try catch blocks? Just to see if the exception is caught and what kind of exception it is.

Comment: the exception is on the first question, read it plz. and it ocurrs when i move the map or i do zoom on the map, this only happens with this kind of thread... before doesn't happens to me

Comment: As i read in google: This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

Comment: i put 5000 miliseconds of sleep and it seems to work for 10 or 15 seconds, but then crash again ....

Comment: You must be accessing an object from Locate in MyLooper, and you can't do that. Does your MapActivity extends Activity? If yes try the modified version that I'm going to put in my answer.

Comment: Only try the modified version if you are accessing Locate objects in MyLooper. If you're not, then must be something else throwing the exception. Also, it'd be nice to see the updated version of all your code.

Comment: yes ofc i am accesing locate objects in MyLooper, and also, please, tell me how can i protect a variable to be accesed only by one thread at once

Comment: why u have this? public MyLooper(Handler locateHandler)... i can't pass a handler of locate, because i have not a handler on locate!

Comment: To protect a variable from being accessed by more than a thread at once, you can use synchronized methods or statements. (Basically encapsulate your variable with a method and declare it like: public synchronized void method() )http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: That's why I was asking is MapActivity extended an Activity class. Does calling new Handler() throw an error?

Comment: Try the updated version of my example. Put a constructor in MyLooper that receives an Handler, and then use the handler to post code to the Locate thread. Calling new Handler() in Locate shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: what? but i dont have a handler on my app, how i can pass a handler if i dont have one?

Comment: The Handler class it's part of the Android SDK. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because you are calling the update My/Friends Positions from both an onClick and the timer. You need to do it just on the timer's handler. Here's the simplest timer/handler

In main activity have

```
Thread myRefreshThread = null;
```

in on Create have

```
this.myRefreshThread = new Thread(new TimerThread());
this.myRefreshThread.start();
```

Have inner class

```
  class TimerThread implements Runnable {
      // @Override
      public void run() {
         Message m = new Message();
         m.what = YourMainClassName.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER;
         // define this as a constant in your manin class/activity
         while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // Your processing
            // You can put data in a Bundle and send the Bundle
            // in the message with m.setData(Bundle b)
            YourMainClassName.this.myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
            try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);// sleeps 1 second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

         }
      }

   }
```

and the handler

```
 Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
      /** Gets called on every message that is received */
      // @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

         switch (msg.what) {
            case YourMainClassName.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER:
               // get the data out of the bundle
               // update the map overlay here and NOWHERE ELSE
               break;
         }
      }
```

Comment: P.S. Passing data from a service to the app CAN be done via Preferences but it's not the best way. If it's a remote service you can send it via aidl and a remote interface. If it's a local service you can probably do it in an easier way, but I've only used remote services so am not sure how

Comment: i never use the onclick because i never press the button, then it wont be the cause of the crash...